# How to use aligment in a list?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, lists

At the moment:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item $3,6,9,12, \dots$
    \item $3,5,7,9,11, \dots$
    \item $2,3,5,7,11,13, \dots$
    \item \includegraphics[scale=1]{pattern_1.pdf}
    \item \includegraphics[scale=1]{pattern_2.pdf}
    \item \includegraphics[scale=1]{pattern_3.pdf}
    \item \includegraphics[scale=1]{pattern_4.pdf}
\end{enumerate}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem comes from the fact that graphics are laid on the base line. A solution uses `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

 \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item $3,6,9,12, \dots$
    \item $3,5,7,9,11, \dots$
    \item $2,3,5,7,11,13, \dots$
    \item \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{pattern_1.pdf}}
    \item \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{pattern_2.pdf}}
    \item \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{pattern_3.pdf}}
    \item \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{pattern_4.pdf}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height` would be better than `-0.95\height`, because the images can have different height.

Comment: @egreg: Perfectly right.  I'll add it, thanks! Just a question : isn't `\ht\strutbox` the same as `0.7\baselineskip`?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`, and then add `valign=t` to the options of `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item $3,6,9,12, \dots$
    \item $3,5,7,9,11, \dots$
    \item $2,3,5,7,11,13, \dots$
    \item \includegraphics[height=8mm,valign=t]{pattern_1.pdf}
    \item \includegraphics[height=10mm,valign=t]{pattern_2.pdf}
    \item \includegraphics[height=12mm,valign=t]{pattern_3.pdf}
    \item \includegraphics[height=15mm,valign=t]{pattern_4.pdf}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]